# Calculating percentages by group in R

Tags: r

My data set looks like this:
[image: Data set]
The data is from course student evaluations. The columns include categorical data for courses, and numerical data for scores in various criteria from a rubric. I am trying to use R to calculate the percentage for values equal or greater than 3 for all the columns by course. I can't figure out a straight forward way that is faster than doing it manually.
Thank you
Fernando

Comment: Welcome to SO! Rather than posting a picture of your data you can post it using `dput(data)`.

Answer (score 1):

The `tidyverse` packages are well suited for this kind of tasks.

```
library(tidyverse)
```

First let's create some dummy data.

```
df <- tibble(`1..Course` = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=5),
             col1 = sample(c(NA,1:5), 15, replace=TRUE),
             col2 = sample(c(NA,1:5), 15, replace=TRUE),
             col3 = sample(c(NA,1:5), 15, replace=TRUE))
```

Now, for each column we want to look which values are >3:

```
df$col1 > 3
 [1] FALSE    NA  TRUE    NA FALSE    NA    NA FALSE    NA FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE    NA FALSE
```

So we get a boolean, which will be automatically converted to numbers (0 and 1) if we try to take the sum. So computing a proportion is just taking the mean!

But there are missing values, so we will explicitly ignore them:

```
mean(df$col1 > 3, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 0.2222222
```

So we know how to do it for a whole column, now we can use the functions from the tidyverse to do it `by` course:

```
df %>%
  group_by(`1..Course`) %>%
  summarize(prop_col1 = mean(col1 > 3, na.rm = TRUE),
            prop_col2 = mean(col2 > 3, na.rm = TRUE),
            prop_col3 = mean(col3 > 3, na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  `1..Course` prop_col1 prop_col2 prop_col3
#  <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 A          0.333      0.2       0.5 
#2 B          0          0.75      0.2 
#3 C          0.25       0         0.25
```

And it's done.

Possibly, you may want to do this for every criteria without typing them. So you need to see the criteria type as a variable, and convert your data.frame to long format. Then the same code applies.

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-`1..Course`, names_to="criterium") %>%
  group_by(`1..Course`, criterium) %>%
  summarize(prop_value = mean(value > 3, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time. I followed the commands. I think I have a problem with the column names and rows. The course name column is not identified as a category and so it is not grouping them by course.I tried to do it with just one criterion and this is what happened:     STEPSum2020Assessment %>%
+ group_by("1..Course") %>%
+ summarise(knowledge = mean(Knowledge > 2, na.rm=TRUE))
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  `"1..Course"` knowledge
  <chr>             <dbl>
1 1..Course         0.842

Comment: my apologies for the messy message but this text editor is weird and if I press return it closes the comment. But going back to the previous comment. If I just use group_by(Course) ,which is the actual column name in the csv file, R doesn't recognize it. Somehow the columname in R is 1..Course. I think that is where the problem is and I am not sure how to fix it. I am really bad at R!!!!! thanks again. Fernando

Comment: When indicating the grouping variable, you need to give the variable name, not a string. So you should not use quotation marks: `group_by(Course)`. In your case since `1..Course` is not syntactically correct (should not start with a digit), you need to use backticks (I edited my answer to illustrate). Or you can simply `rename()` that column to a syntactic name. The name `1..Course` suggests something strange while reading the csv file (duplicate column names or something). You can ask about that in a separate question, making sure to include all relevant information.

Comment: @Alexilok, I will try that! Since I am having this issue with column names, when importing csv files using read.csv(), should I process the file before beginning to analyze the data in R. I understand that if I don't specify any of the parameters in read.csv it by default assumes that the first row is column names and the first column are rownames, is that correct?

Comment: I would do the processing in R, so that it stays reproducible if the csv change. Yes, see the options `header` and `col.names`. I tend to prefer `read_csv()` part of the tidyverse, mostly equivalent to `read.csv()`, sometimes more practical. To learn more about how to use the tidyverse approach that works great for most analyses, I highly recommend the book [R for data science](r4ds.had.co.nz) available for free online.

Comment: I was finally able to get it done following your recommendations. I ended up changing the name of the column and saving the data frame and then the pivot_longer function to calculate the percentages for all criteria by course. I also went checked out the online free book you recommended and plan to use it. This was extremely helpful. Thank you so much.